# How can I have a different robots.txt file subdomain and main domain in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a laravel project that has a main domain and a subdomain setup in routes/web.php like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.example.com'), function() {
    // subdomain routes
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.com'), function() {
    // domain routes
});
```

how can i separate robots.txt files for main domain and subdomain? if you going to the path of robots.txt, domain and subdomain return the same file. Laravel read default file in public folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Solution for NGINX.

Before server section:

```
map $host $robots_file {
  default robots.txt;
  site.com robots-site.txt;
  www.site.com robots-site.txt;
}
```

Inside server section:

```
location = /robots.txt {
  try_files /$robots_file =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you can use on **Apache** servers is to create a custom rule that routes robots.txt depending on the subdomain.

You can have in the **public** folder, two robots files, for example **robots.txt** and **robots-disallow.txt**.

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

robots-disallow.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

In the **public/.htaccess** file, create a new rule which will indicate that if the request is to one of the indicated subdomains, the path to robots.txt will show the content of robots-disallow.txt, otherwise it will show the original content of robots.txt file.

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1|sub2\.domain\.com$
     RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-disallow.txt
</IfModule>
```

In this way, when sub1.domain.com is accessed, the sitemap will be displayed indicating that the content should not be indexed, and in the main domain the general robots.txt.

This solution works not only in Laravel but also in any **apache environment**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it this that are in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing)

```
Route::domain('{account}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: how does this answer what the OP is asking?

Comment: the question is about how to handle requests to a subdomain. In Laravel you don't need to create two robots.txt, because you already have a Route method to handle those queries. **READ THE DOCUMENTATION.**

Comment: "How can I have a different robots.txt file subdomain and main domain in Laravel?" read what the OP wants

Comment: Read my answer: __In Laravel you don't need to create two robots.txt, because is already have a Route method to handle those queries.__

Comment: I know that, but OP needs two robots.txt files so that he cant configure accordingly for the two domains.